# A speaks truth 3 out of 4 times (Conditional Probability)

Tags: probability

I know this question is very easy but I am having a conceptual doubt in this question.

A is known to speak truth 3 out of 4 times.If he reports that a 6 is the outcome of an event of throwing a dice, what is the probability that a 6 was actually the outcome.

My attempt :

$$P = \frac{\frac{3}{4} \times \frac{1}{6}        }{\frac{3}{4}\times \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{4}\times \frac{5}{6}\times\frac{1}{5}  }   = \boxed{\frac{3}{4}}.$$

In the last term I am multiplying with 1/5 because he has to speak 6 when the result was not 6,  so he has only one choice out of the 5 choices to speak 6.

By calculating this way P(e) = 3/4,  but the answer to this question given in many books is 3/8.
Where am I doing mistake?

Comment: That question involves 2 people and my question is a simpler as it involves a single person.On basis of that scenario I am having an answer different to this scenario according to many books.

Comment: Oh, I just saw the the titles were the same. And that post was recent. Hehe.

Comment: If the result of the die is not a six, will $A$ always say that it is a six or will he say that it is a result other than the actual result uniformly at random?

Comment: A tells that the outcome of the event was 6 so he is telling only 6 as the outcome of the event.

Comment: In my (and apparently the various books interpretation) if the roll is any of 1,2,3,4,5 and the person decides to lie **he will always say the roll is a six**.  As a result, your $\cdot \frac{1}{5}$ is unnecessary as there is no chance for him to *not* say so.  If you were to assume that if he decides to lie that he picks one of the available remaining numbers uniformly at random to choose to say, then your answer would be correct.

Comment: But isnt this a wierd assumption in a question of probability to assume that a specific event is bound to occur when any other events can take its place?

Comment: Questions like these and similar monty hall or boy-girl problems, it must be made *totally* clear how people act, otherwise multiple interpretations can occur each with different answers.  What if it happens to be that the person whenever he sees a six is actually rolled and decides to tell the truth instead of saying something about the dice decides to tell you what the weather outside is like (truthfully).  In this case, the only time that he ever says anything about the number six is when it is not a six, and the probability would be zero.

Comment: The simplest and most common interpretation would be that once the dice are rolled the person is asked a very clear question.  "*Is the result a six?*" to which his only responses are "*Yes it is a six*" or "*No it is not a six*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on the distribution of what the person would say if he were to lie.

If he is equally likely to say any of the 5 wrong dice rolls when lying, then the likelihood that a 6 was actually rolled is 3/4, as you calculated.

If however the person had been asked, "Did the dice roll a 6?" he would either answer that it was a 6 or it wasn't. In this case, if the outcome wasn't a 6 and he chooses to lie, he would for sure say it was a 6.  In this scenario, the likelihood that a 6 was actually rolled is 3/8.

These are not the only two possible scenarios.  It is possible that when the person lies, he is equally likely to claim the outcome was any integer from 1 to 100 other than the true outcome. If this were true, the likelihood of saying 6 as a lie decreases, and thus the likelihood that 6 is true increases.

Since we are not given the information about the lying distribution, we would have to base our answer on a prior assumption of what that distribution would likely be, which of course is not objective. If indeed the person had been asked, "What was the outcome of the roll?" we would intuitively assume that his lying distribution would be uniform over the 5 possible but false outcomes.

This would be a bit more complicated if let's say two dice were rolled and the person claimed the total sum was 12.  Should we assume if he were to lie that he would be equally likely to claim any of the 10 wrong but possible outcomes? Or that the likelihood of him falsely claiming a certain outcome is proportionate to the true likelihood of that outcome?  If the latter, than the likelihood that 12 is true is approximately 3/4 (only approximately, as the likelihood of him falsely claiming 12 depends on the true outcome.  If 7, then likelihood of saying 12 is 1/30, if 3, then it would be 1/34 - calculations get complicated.) But if he would lie uniformally, the odds of him saying 2 falsely increase and the likelihood of 2 being the truth decreases.

There could also be situations where the person's claim affects our assumptions about the lying distribution. If say 100 dice were rolled and the person claimed that the sum was say 105 (extremely unlikely) we would say intuitively that it's much more probable that he lies uniformally than proportionately, and calculate accordingly.

In conclusion, there is no definite answer to the question without knowing the under-lying distribution.

Comment: So you mean to say that the answer could be 3/4 or 3/8 depending on the interpretation of tge question?

Comment: Correct.  Or perhaps the answer is not enough information.

Answer (score 2):

This is a conditional probability problem. We can address it using the definition of a conditional probability.

We know that the probability of rolling a $6$ on a fair die is $\frac{1}{6}.$ We also know that this person tells the truth with probability $\frac{3}{4}.$

Then the probability that the die is actually a $6$ if the dude says it is can be computed as follows:
$$P = \frac{\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{3}{4}}{\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{3}{4} + \frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{4}}.$$
Make sure you understand why this is.

Simplifying, we have that
$$P = \frac{\frac{1}{8}}{\frac{1}{8} + \frac{5}{24}} = \frac{3}{3 + 5} = \boxed{\frac{3}{8}}.$$

Comment: In the denomanator in the 2nd term why arent you multiplying with 1/5 because when you have ensured that the die has not rolled to give 6 and that A is speaking lie then we have to also ensure that A speaks 6 out of the 5 possibilities of speaking lie.

Comment: Think about it in this way. One of two things could have happened. Either the dude is telling the truth **and** the die actually rolled $6,$ or he was lying **and** the die did not roll a $6.$ The probability of the first case is simply $\frac{1}{6} \times \frac{3}{4}.$ The probability of the second case is $\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{4}.$

Comment: In the 2nd case when you have ensured that the die has not rolled to give 6 and that A is speaking lie then we have to also ensure that A speaks 6 out of the 5 possibilities of speaking lie.eg if the dice gives 4 then he can also say 3 but he says 6.In your answer you are counting this possibility also

Comment: From the information we are given - that the guy said the die rolled $6$ and he lies a quarter of the time - the only two possibilities are the ones I gave above. We **know** that the guy said $6,$ so either he's being truthful or he's lying. If he's lying, which we **know** happens a quarter of the time, then the probability is $\frac{5}{6} \times \frac{1}{4}.$ Hope this makes sense.

Comment: When the die shows 5 then A can speak truth in 1 way and a lie in 5 ways(1,2,3,4,6).So shouldn't we ensure that he speaks 6 out of the 5 possibilities?

Comment: The tricky thing about conditional probability is that we must distinguish between what we know and what we do not know. All we know is that person $A$ tells the truth $\frac{3}{4}$ of the time, which is information we can use. We do not know what the die rolled. We can only compute the probability based on $A$'s known accuracy.